# Info about Foursquare's app Layout

Tags: android, foursquare

look at this:
http://www.eurodroid.com/pics/android_foursquare_update_1.jpg

Someone knows how is structured this layout?
Is a 3 tab layout, but the content of this tab?
Is a table, a ListAdapter, what is?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of that tab specifically is just a customized ListView. As pointed out by Bryan, you can browse the source code to see the exact XML layouts they used.

Answer (score 4):

[The Foursquare app for Android is open source.](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/)  I believe what you are looking for is their [main_activity.xml](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/main/res/layout/main_activity.xml%3a):

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <!-- Background color should be the last value in the selected tab gradient. -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dip"
        android:background="#4d4d4d">

    <TabWidget
      android:id="@android:id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <!-- A paddingTop of zero will remove the strip below the tabs. -->
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" />

  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```